# Having issue when adding a common value to every elements in array using Jolt

Tags: jolt

I am currently using Jolt to work on this input:

```
{
    "banking_account": {
        "accounts": [
            {
                "accountId": "account1"
            },
            {
                "accountId": "account2",
                "nickname": "nickname2"
            }
        ]
    },

    "account_balance": {
        "total_value": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "100.00"
        },
        "balance_accounts": [
            {
                "id": "id1"
            },
            {
                "id": "id2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And the expected output is:

```
{
    "Data": {
        "Accounts": [
            {
                "AccountId": "account1",
                "Account": {
                    "Identification": [
                        "id1",
                        "id2"
                    ]
                },
                "Currency": "USD"
            },
            {
                "AccountId": "account2",
                "NickName": "nickname2",
                "Account": {
                    "Identification": [
                        "id1",
                        "id2"
                    ]
                },
                "Currency": "USD"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And here is my current spec:

```
[
    {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
            "banking_account": {
                "accounts": {
                    "*": {
                        "accountId": "Data.Accounts.[&1].AccountId",
                        "nickname": "Data.Accounts.[&1].NickName"
                    }
                }
            },
            "account_balance": {
                "total_value": {
                    "currency_code": "Data.Accounts.[&1].Currency"
                },
                "balance_accounts": {
                    "*": {
                        "id": "Data.Accounts.[&1].Account.Identification"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

And here is my current output:

```
{
    "Data": {
        "Accounts": [
            {
                "AccountId": "account1",
                "Account": {
                    "Identification": "id1"
                }
            },
            {
                "AccountId": "account2",
                "NickName": "nickname2",
                "Account": {
                    "Identification": "id2"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So I am having two questions:

1. Why is the "Currency" value missing? Even if I added something like

```
"account_balance": {
    "total_value": {
        "currency_code": "Data.Accounts.[&1].Currency"
    }
}
```

2. How to map both two balances accounts to both two accounts? Now it seems like an 1->1 mapping; and I wish to have a 2*2 mapping.

Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this spec for your solution but point 2 is not covered in this and I have added reason for 2nd:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "banking_account": {
        "accounts": {
          "*": {
            "accountId": "Data.Accounts.[&1].AccountId",
            "nickname": "Data.Accounts.[&1].NickName"
          }
        }
      },
      "account_balance": {
        "total_value": {
          "currency_code": "Data.Currency"
        },
        "balance_accounts": {
          "*": {
            "id": "Data.Identification"
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Data": {
        "Accounts": {
          "*": {
            "*": "Data.Accounts.[&1].&",
            "@(2,Currency)": {
              "USD": {
                "#USD": "Data.Accounts.[&2].Currency"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "Identification": "Data.Identification"
      }
    }
   }
]
```

& This will answer your two questions :

1 : Why is the "Currency" value missing? Even if I added something like

So you are basically populating a single field element as multiple fields in an array with [&1] which is not possible that's why its not populating.
To do such a case you need to create new elements that will be populating in the Accounts array if you see my spec I am adding a new Current field in every object of Accounts array ->

```
"Accounts": {
              "*": {
                "*": "Data.Accounts.[&1].&",
                "@(2,Currency)": { //Going 2 levels up to get to currency
                  "USD": { //If else to check Currency is USD
                    "#USD": "Data.Accounts.[&2].Currency" //Adding the field in each object of Accounts array.
                  }
                }
              }
```

2. How to map both two balances accounts to both two accounts? Now it seems like an 1->1 mapping; and I wish to have a 2*2 mapping.

--> This can be achieved in the similar way I have done for 1 but this will again require alot of hardcoding in JOlt.

So my suggestion is to keep both Currency and Identification outside Accounts Array in Data as single object.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me a lot to understand the Jolt behaviors. It seems to be better to avoid one-to-many mappings in Jolt; otherwise it requires much more code and logic.